# ios - Making UIScrollView scroll smoothly

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

In my iPad application, i've a scroll view that lists images of 20 video albums. The list of 20 images will be sent by server.
Now when the user reaches end of scroll view, i've to send a request to get next 10 videos details. 
After fetching the data, i want to add them to the scroll view at the end. But I want to delete the 10 videos at the beginning. So that at a time scroll view will  show only 20 video details all the time.
When user scrolls again to the end, i'll send request to server, get next 10 video details and add them to the scroll view, remove 10 beginning video details from scroll view...... and similarly when user scrolls to the beginning i'll fetch 10 previous videos and repeat the same. 
Here i want to make sure the scrolling must be smooth and don't want to have flickers in scroll view. can some one suggest to have better scroll view coding to achieve my requirements please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem here will be in setting up cell recycling. It's not that hard to do, I have a couple examples of which you can look at, one being [here](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/JTrackView). You'll need to make some changes to that code of course, it is set up in "pages" — Only one view on screen at any one time, and I don't think that's what you want.

Aside from that...

Your critical part here will be in designing your data source in a way that allows removing of old items, and adding new items, without skipping items.

For instance, the way I might approach this is to render the "last" item in your scroll view, the same as you want the first item in the scrollview to be. When the user gets to the last item, set your content offset to the start of the scrollview without animation (haven't actually tried this, so there may be a jolt that you don't want, test it and see). This will give the appearance of endless scrolling. Your data source would simply overwrite old indexes when adding new items, instead of adding to the end of an array for instance.

Answer (score 3):

If your code contains `scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;` Then please remove this part of code.
It will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting then in the form of a grid view, I suggest you take a look at [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). That grid view supports cell queueing and dequeueing, which does exactly what you describe.

You can also use the delegate method scrollViewDidScroll: to determine if you're at the bottom of the scrollview and trigger the download of the next set of albums.